# Classic ASP Pages Returned Within MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp-classic, refactoring

Is it possible to directly return a Classic ASP web page as an Action Result etc? I have just inherited a stack of Classic ASP applications that are still being maintained and even extended.

I am looking to stop writing new Classic ASP code move to an MVC based setup (as that is the direction the department is going). Therefore I am looking for any options that don't require me to rewrite all the applications but allow me to slowly add features written in ASP.Net.

Ideally I would like to organise features around controllers etc and then return existing ASP pages as the result of Actions. I'd like the URL structure to look the same as a normal MVC site.

Any thoughts or advice? I know there are other posts on this. Haven't seen any that are trying to return ASP pages via Action Result etc.

Thanks

Graeme

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Is it possible to directly return a Classic ASP web page as an Action Result etc?

No. The best you could do is redirect. If you are migrating some legacy classic ASP site to ASP.NET MVC you could do it progressively. You can start replacing pages one by one by introducing controllers, models and views. `iframes` could also be used as a temporary solution to interoperate between the two technologies during the migration.

Comment: Could I write a Custom Action Result that wrapped the ASP page whole in an iframe or something?

Comment: Yes, you can. For example it could look like this `return AspResult("/foo.asp");` and the custom action result will generate a simple HTML page and inside the body it will render an iframe with its src property pointing to the .asp page passed as argument. But in this case I really don't see what benefit does the controller brings. You could perfectly fine have redirected directly to the .asp page from the client.

Comment: Just wondered if it would help me keep the URL structure looking like an MVC app? The controller would let me use the same logging via attributes etc. as normal MVC sites. Also I can then structure everything in an initial go into controllers and then give it a structure. Then get other developers to slowly replace the pages with MVC views.

Comment: @GraemeMiller, the URL structure will not look like an MVC app. You will still be using iframes and those frames will point to legacy urls with classic structure.

Comment: Sorry I meant to the user. The URL in the address bar. The user won't know where the iframe points.